# What's a good minimal pair to highlight interrogative prosody in English?

Tags: english, prosody, intonation, praat, interrogatives

I want to show my students how intonation contours in Praat can help identify English interrogatives. An obvious example is "He's coming." vs "He's coming?" -- but perhaps those of you more familiar with prosody or intonation have better ideas in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is often helpful to avoid voiceless sounds as much as possible in prosody stimuli, to get a clearer pitch track. For example, "Mary will win" has no voiceless sounds (from: Pierrehumbert, J. (2000). Tonal elements and their alignment. In Prosody: Theory and experiment (pp. 11-36). Springer Netherlands.).

For demonstration purposes, you may also want to use a longer sentence.

Comment: Yep. And among voiced sounds, you'll want to avoid voiced fricatives, which are not handled well by the pitch analysis.